# How can I split a Polygon by a Line?

Tags: algorithm, split, polygon

As shown below,

[image]

Is it possible to split a Polygon by a Line? (into  two Polygons). If the line doesn't go all the way across the polygon it would fail.

Is this possible? If so, how would I do this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I had to do this recently. Just walking the polygon won't work for concave polygons, as in your diagram. Below is a sketch of my algorithm, inspired by the [Greiner-Hormann](http://www.inf.usi.ch/hormann/papers/Greiner.1998.ECO.pdf) polygon clipping algorithm. Splitting is both easier and harder than polygon clipping. Easier because you only clip against a line instead of a rect or another polygon; harder because you need to keep both sides.

```
Create an empty list of output polygons
Create an empty list of pending crossbacks (one for each polygon)
Find all intersections between the polygon and the line.
Sort them by position along the line.
Pair them up as alternating entry/exit lines.
Append a polygon to the output list and make it current.
Walk the polygon. For each edge:
    Append the first point to the current polygon.
    If there is an intersection with the split line:
        Add the intersection point to the current polygon.
        Find the intersection point in the intersection pairs.
        Set its partner as the crossback point for the current polygon.
        If there is an existing polygon with a crossback for this edge:
            Set the current polygon to be that polygon.
        Else
            Append a new polygon and new crossback point to the output lists and make it current.
        Add the intersection point to the now current polygon.
```

Answer (score 13):

It's possible, but if the polygon is not convex then splitting it across a line potentially leads to more than two polygons.

Traverse the polygons edges, and for each edge determine whether it intersects the line. Find the first such edge which does so. Continue traversing until you find another such edge, but add each you encounter along the way to a new polygon (including the part of the first edge which was split by the line which is on "this side" and likewise for the last edge). Finally, add a closing edge to the new Polygon. Now continue processing edges - on the other side of the line, creating another Polygon in the same manner. You now have two polygons split across the line. The same technique will work, if you are careful, with splitting a non-convex polygon into multiples polygons.

Beware of corner cases such as the line crossing a vertex of the polygon, and the line not intersecting the polygon at all.

**Edit:** As xan points out, this won't handle all non-convex cases properly. This can be fixed with a small modification to the algorithm. Before you add the closing edge as described above, you must first check if any further edge of the original polygon would intersect that closing edge; if so, you close only up to that edge and continue processing further edges from that point.

Comment: Thanks. That's probably what I'll do as soon as I get the time

Comment: I don't think that technique extends so readily to concave polygons. Consider splitting the outline of the letter C with a vertical line. On the left side you'll get two overlapping, half-disc polygons.

Comment: xan, true, this is another case that needs to be handled. When you cross the splitting line, you need to check that you're not then inside a polygon that you've created previously; or rather, make sure that the edge you synthesize doesn't cross another edge.

Answer (score 3):

In 1994, George Vanecek worked out a solution for this in 3D, and published the solution in Graphic Gems V "Spatial Partitioning of the Polygon by a Plane".  The source code is still available in the [Graphic Gems Repository](http://www.realtimerendering.com/resources/GraphicsGems/).

More recently, David Geier published a 2D implementation of Vanecek's algorithm with an explanation of the algorithm.  See [David's Blog:  Splitting an arbitrary polygon by a line](https://web.archive.org/web/20200122185639/https://geidav.wordpress.com/2015/03/21/splitting-an-arbitrary-polygon-by-a-line/)

Answer (score 2):

All you need is a polygon clipping alogrithem. You can see an overview here:
[Polygon clipping](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/misc/misc/graphics/article.php/c8965) I think there are penty implementations out there where you can learn from.

Answer (score 1):

Its perfectly possible. I am assuming you're using Java2d for this. You have find a method in it called as intersects. Using that you can do this.

You might have to modify [this](http://www.koders.com/java/fid058B5904198EB5BA18B9B086CC3B953F96CD2750.aspx) implementation of polygon and write one more intersects method which passes a Line2D object and customize it so that it passes an array polygons (possible since the same line cut can produce infinite polygons - assume a zigzag polygon) or null.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I don't know how I would even go about doing that ( the math involved ). It might have to do with the Line intersecting each of the Polygon's lines. ( and splitting the shape like that ).

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of what polygon library you are using, if it has the standard set of operations it should be able to do this - by using a zero-width polygon rather than a line. Subtract the zero width polygon from the input and you'll have the separate parts.  If your package doesn't support true zero-width polygons then give it the smallest possible width and if necessary undo that slight offset from the results.